# Dynamic Function- Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, plsqldeveloper, dynamicquery

I am trying to create a function by giving 2 variables as inputs. These 2 variables are used dynamically in the function. Am using a select statement in the beginning of the loop to find the primary key column in a particular table. This column is assign to a variable value1. Am using this value1 variable as a sequence variable.

```
create FUNCTION Test(schemaname in varchar2, tablename in varchar2)
return number
IS cnpParmId NUMBER;
good VARCHAR(1) := 'F';
exist VARCHAR(1) := 'F';
value1 varchar2(500);
  
begin
good  := 'F';
exist := 'F';
loop
   SELECT cols.column_name into value1
        FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
        WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME= 'tablename' 
        And cols.OWNER='schemaname'
        And cons.constraint_type = 'P'
        AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
        AND cons.owner = cols.owner
        ORDER BY cols.table_name, cols.position; 
  
   select schemaname.value1_seq.nextval into cnpParmId from dual;
   begin
      select 'T' into good from dual 
      where cnpParmId not in 
      (select value1 from schemaname.tablename);
      exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then good := 'F';
   end;
   exit when good = 'T';
end loop;
return cnpParmId;
end;
/

Test(XYZ,ABC);
```

but am getting the following errors:

> Error(21,11): PLS-00487: Invalid reference to variable 'SCHEMANAME'
>
> Error(21,22): PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
>
> Error(23,7): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>
> Error(25,38): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Answer (score 1):

When you introduce variables as table or column names you need to do a dynamic query using [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm).

Your sequence query should be:

```
execute immediate 'select ' || schemaname || '.nextval from dual' into cnpParmId;
```

And your "get the return value" query should be:

```
execute immediate
  'select ''T'' from dual where cnpParmId not in ' ||
  '(select value1 from ' || schemaname || '.' || tablename || ')' into good;
```

Also note that your query to get `value1` is looking for the *literal* values `schemaname` and `tablename`:

```
SELECT cols.column_name into value1
    FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
    WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME= 'tablename'
    And cols.OWNER='schemaname'
    ... and so on
```

You *can* use variables to represent values, so just get rid of the single quotes around the variable names:

```
SELECT cols.column_name into value1
    FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
    WHERE cols.TABLE_NAME= tablename
    And cols.OWNER=schemaname
    ... and so on
```